# how to build igmp query generator in c/c++ under linux

Tags: c++, linux, perl, sockets, igmp

I am looking for a c/c++ test that works as IGMP (raw socket) query generator, or how can I add a synthetic test that works IGMP query generator I found a perl igmp query generator (http://www.coexsi.fr/publications/igmp-querier/igmp-querier.pl),
but actually I don't have an idea how to test that, or what is the purpose of this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this project as a start: [igmpquery](https://code.google.com/p/igmpquery/source/browse/trunk/igmpquery.c)